# Application has stopped-Android studio

Tags: java, android

I've been searching forums, but it seems that I'm pretty much the only one with this problem.I've created a simple layout with a button in it using java file.However, when I run it, I get error "Application has stopped".When I create a button in xml file it's working fine.Everything's imported as I'm not getting any errors.Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        RelativeLayout r=new RelativeLayout(this);

        Button b=new Button(this);
        r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        b.setText("KEK");
        r.addView(b);



        setContentView(r);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this

```
    RelativeLayout r=new RelativeLayout(this);

    Button b=new Button(this);
    r.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    b.setText("KEK");
    r.addView(b);
```

You should declare a `xml file` to your `setContentView()` otherwise you won't be able to call `findViewById()`

### EDIT

Let's say a few issues I found.

If you do this `setContentView(r);`

You should declare `Id's` for each `view` on your `r`

If you want to use `r` as a `View` you'll have to add the `Toolbar` since you are trying to `findViewById()` and in your `r` there are not a `Toolbar` and the same with `FloatingActionButton`.

*Note: If you want to use your `r view` add all of the views that you want to use on it, otherwise it will always crash.*

Comment: So, I assume it's better to use xml to create views?Instead of wasting time in java file

Comment: @igorcar1994 For sure :) If you want views you add those views on xml file, if you want to add it dynamically you could do it aswell but this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use findViewById(R.id.something) if you doesn't have set a content view from an XML layout where these IDs are contained.

If you wouldn't use any XML layout, you must create all views by yourself like:

```
//with the right arguments passed at the constructor
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton();
```